# Are all knex queries run in a transaction by default?

Tags: mysql, transactions, deadlock, knex.js

I'm not using `knex.transaction`, `knex.forUpdate`, `knex.forShare`, `knex.batchInsert` or any method that explicitly creates a transaction, yet I'm having a DEADLOCK error in my code. If knex.js does not create transactions by default, why does it create locks?

**UPDATE**

When those queries are executed twice very rapidly, I get a DEADLOCK exception.

```
let subquery2 = knex.select('pv2.*').from('projects_versions as pv2').innerJoin('versions_history as vh', 'pv2.version_id', 'vh.version_id').orderBy('vh.id', 'desc');
let subquery = knex.select('x.version_id').from(subquery2.as('x')).whereRaw('x.project_id = pv.project_id').limit(1);

let result = (await knex.raw('DELETE pv FROM projects_versions AS pv WHERE pv.version_id = ? AND NOT version_id = ?', [versionToDiscard, subquery]))[0];

if (!result.affectedRows) {
    await knex('projects_versions').update({ version_id: fifthVersion }).where('version_id', versionToDiscard);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knex creates implicit transaction by default when runnin migrations. Otherwise knex doesn't create any implicit locks.

There is just too little information in the question to be able to answer anything more useful to this.

Comment: I'm not talking about running a migration. It seems like knex **does** create implicit locks, since I get some DEADLOCK errors. I just can't find where. For example, when the query described in my updated question is executed twice very rapidly, I get the error. Perhaps it is a behaviour of subqueries to impose locks?

Comment: Knex *does not* create implicit locks. Database might create them (knex just sends the queries to the database to be executed, knex does not send any extra locking queries). Anyways knex does use multiple connections to send queries so you cannot be certain about execution order unless you wait for result of earlier query before sending the next one.